# Best known bounds for a product over primes in an interval

Tags: nt.number-theory

As the title ask, what is the best lower and upper bounds for the product below :
$$ \prod \limits_{x < p \leq y} \frac{p+1}{p}$$
such that $p$ denote the prime numbers in which fullfil the conditions under the product ?

Comment: Why do you not simply ask for upper and lower bounds for (1), since (2) is the reciprocal of (1)? Also, it's best to use a more descriptive title. You can  use LaTeX in the title, so you could change it to "Best known upper and lower bounds for $\prod_{x<p\le y} (p+1)/p$.

Comment: you are right !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your product is the following $$\prod_{y<p\leq x} \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$
You can use the fact that $$\prod_{y<p\leq x} \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\leq \prod_{y<p\leq x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{6} \prod_{y<p\leq x} \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$ Note that $\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)},$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. According to the best current explicit results of Pierre Dusart: For $x > 1$,
$$\prod_{p\leq x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)< \frac{\exp(-\gamma)}{\ln{x}} \left(1+\frac{0.2}{\ln^3{x}}\right)$$
and for $x \geq 2278382,$ 
$$\prod_{p\leq x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)> \frac{\exp(-\gamma)}{\ln{x}} \left(1-\frac{0.2}{\ln^3{x}}\right)$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant $(\gamma \sim 0.5772157)$  and you are done!

Comment: In Dusart's most recent paper (which I cited in my answer), one gets $\ln(x)^3$ instead of $\ln(x)^2$ in the denominator of the error term (at the cost of changing $x\geq 2973$ to $x\geq 2278382$).  I'm only pointing this out so that those who come to MathOverflow and see this is the accepted answer don't think this is the best bound available.

Comment: @Pace Nielsen oh yes you are right! I will edit the post.

Comment: Also, you don't want to use Dusart's bounds for $\prod_{p\leq x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$, but rather his bounds for the reciprocal (which are not the same as reciprocating the bounds of the reciprocal).

Comment: In the second inequality, the factor $\frac{\pi^2}6$ is quite wasteful for nontrivial $y$; a better bound for $\prod_{p>y} \big( 1-\frac1{p^2} \big)^{-1}$ is $\frac y{y-1}$, resulting from the telescoping product $\prod_{n>y} \big( 1-\frac1{n^2} \big)^{-1} = \frac{\lfloor y\rfloor +1}{\lfloor y\rfloor}$.

Answer (score 3):

The best source for explicit, unconditional bounds on such products that I'm aware of is in the work of Pierre Dusart.  See his paper [Explicit estimates of some functions over primes](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11139-016-9839-4).

In Section 5.4, Theorem 5.9, he gives upper and lower bounds for
$$
Q(x):=\prod_{p\leq x}\frac{p}{p-1}.
$$
Using these, we can get bounds on
$$
Q(y)/Q(x)=\prod_{x< p\leq y}\frac{p}{p-1}.
$$
Notice that the fraction you want is
$$
\frac{p+1}{p}=\frac{p}{p-1}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
so you have reduced to bounding
$$
\prod_{x<p\leq y}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)
$$
which can be done by standard techniques.

(Note that Dusart's bounds are for $x\geq 2278382$, but for small values of $x$ and $y$ you can do an explicit computation.)  Alternatively, you could work directly with the fraction you want (instead of $p/(p-1)$) and use the same techniques as Dusart.

Comment: @Wojowu Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Though Dusart bounds are good ones for $\,\prod\limits_{p \le x}{\left(1 -1/p\right)}$, I think a better idea to the prime product asked by Ahmad is to explore the Dedekind psi function, used in the theory of modular functions, defined as $\,\psi(n)/n = \prod\limits_{p|n}\left( 1 +\frac{1}{p} \right)$.